# GWT capturing drag & drop events

Tags: gwt, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to capture dragover and drop events. Right now I'm capturing those events adding a dom handler to my RootLayoutPanel:

```
dragOverHandler = RootLayoutPanel.get().addBitlessDomHandler(this, DragOverEvent.getType());
dropHandler = RootLayoutPanel.get().addBitlessDomHandler(this, DropEvent.getType());
```

The problem is this code does not capture the events when showing a popup and the drag/drop is over the popup itself or the glass around it.

I have also tried using a native preview handler, but it seems it is not called on dragover nor drop events:

```
Event.addNativePreviewHandler(new Event.NativePreviewHandler() {            
    @Override
    public void onPreviewNativeEvent(NativePreviewEvent event) {
        GWT.log(event.getNativeEvent().getType());  
    }
});
```

Is there a straight way to capture all dragover and drop events in my app?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `RootPanel.get()` instead of `RootLayoutPanel.get()`.

FYI, `RootLayoutPanel.get()` adds the `RootLayoutPanel` singleton to the `RootPanel.get()`; `RootPanel.get()` wraps the document's `<body>` inside a `RootPanel`, so it should capture everything (provided the *body* fills the viewport, which the `RootLayoutPanel` ensures).