# GWT NativePreviewHandler is not aware about drag & drop events

Tags: gwt, drag-and-drop, event-handling

I'm trying to do similar stuff as in this post [GWT capturing drag & drop events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12900945/gwt-capturing-drag-drop-events)

I'm capturing dragover and drop events adding a dom handler to my RootPanel:

```
RootPanel.get().addDomHandler(new DropHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onDrop(DropEvent event) {
        // do stuff
    }
}, DropEvent.getType());
```

I also have a widget and a drop event handler for it. The handler stops propagation.

The handler added to the RootPanel works good unless I drag or drop over that widget.

I tried to use NativePreviewHandler instead, but it seems not working with those events as described in the post I mentioned above.

Comment: I don't understand your problem, you can drag/drop your widget on the RootPanel and the onDrop is called right? Than you drop the same widget on another widget with a DropHandler and only the later is called? Am i right?

Comment: From what I see, it seems to be "ByDesign", take a look to: https://gwt.googlesource.com/gwt/+/master/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/client/impl/DOMImplStandard.java you can see that dispatchDragEvent() is not calling DOM.previewEvent(evt);